# Standard Deviation Of Fundamental Frequency Of Males and Females

Tags: frequency, voicing, variation, voice-biometrics

I know that it fundamental frequency is usually considered to be normally distributed, and that females have a higher variance in their distribution than males. What is the variance of the fundamental frequency across gender?

What about a within subject design? For a given person, how much can I expect the fundamental frequency to vary? Based on the population results, I would expect the variance to be higher for a given female than for a male...correct?

Edit: My population is expected to be adult males and females of north american english. I am looking for the standard deviation within steady-state vowels during normal conversational speech.

Comment: Er ... what is your question? Can you give a little more background of what you are talking about?

Comment: Could you please phrase your question in the form of a question?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things have to be clarified in your question. First, you need to say what the theoretical population of fundamental frequencies is – do you mean "in all instances of speech" (excluding musical and other non-speech uses of phonation)? You also need to specify age range, since infant speech has kind of high F0. You need to specify language: pitch range is a linguistic variable. By "language" I really mean dialect, so apart from the Cantonese vs. English issue, there are geographical and social lects of English (and other languages) that systematically select high pitch range. There is a significant correlation between pitch range and personality type, so that needs to be controlled for (also, as I'm sure you know, you have to be more precise that just stipulating "male" vs. "female"). You might try normalizing speakers by having them produce the lowest-possible pitch and highest-possible pitch on a steady-state vowel, which would give you a basis for guessing their physically-possible pitch range (then you'd need to collect data on the singer / non-singer distinction).